# Confidence metric in the Hough transform: does one exist?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, hough-transform, vision

I am using the Hough Transform algorithm from scikit-image and Python to find the center of a crosshair.

Overall this produces great results, but I need to quantify exactly how well the center of the crosshair has been found. The error propagation due to having multiple lines, I can handle. However, I have not found a way to measure fit confidence (i.e. like a covariance).

This [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01212193) suggests that there may be ways to quantify this, but I have not read it in its entirety. It also suggests smoothing and interpolating the hough space to better locate the maximum of the of peak.

One can also consider fitting a curve (i.e. 2D gaussian or lorentzian) to the hough space of an image, because even a bad covariance is a covariance that can be reported on a scientific document. If this is the correct approach it is still unclear which function one should use to fit data in the hough space. A perfect line becomes a sinusoid, but the accumulation of these sinusoids gives rise to the peak.

Do you know how to quantify the accuracy of a Hough transform? If so how? Would you recommend a different technique for this issue?(hopefully not)

[Successful detection of the corsshair center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er6km.png)

[Hough space region to be fitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItFbQ.png)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions try it here